# F.g group with infinite ends not Q.I to a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, coarse-geometry

Is there any easy example of a finitely generated group with a Cantor set of ends that is not quasi-isometric to a finitely generated free group?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you restrict to torsion-free finitely generated groups: ($\infty$ many ends)$\Leftrightarrow$ (non-trivial free product), while (quasi-isometric to a free group) $\Leftrightarrow$ (free non-abelian).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The free product $\mathbb{Z}^2 \ast \mathbb{Z}$ has infinitely-many ends, but is not quasi-isometric to a free group: furthermore, it is not hyperbolic since it has $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

There is a considerable literature on the subject, see the paper of [Papazoglu (who is usually Papasoglu) and Whyte.](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405274)